# Unable to retrieve account billing address with guest user

Tags: community, permissions, guest-user

I have the following code:

```
prodList = [SELECT ServicePartner__r.Name, ServicePartner__r.BillingAddress, ServicePartner__r.BillingStreet
            FROM Product2 
            WHERE id = :productId AND IsActive = true
            LIMIT 10];
Address adr = prodList[0].ServicePartner__r.BillingAddress;
System.debug('Address str ' + (adr != null? adr.getStreet(): 'null'));
System.debug('BillingStreet ' + prodList[0].ServicePartner__r.BillingStreet);
System.debug('Name ' + prodList[0].ServicePartner__r.Name);
```

- If I run it logged in, the log shows everything right:

*08:39:06:017 USER_DEBUG [29]|DEBUG|Address str San Miguel 1*

*08:39:06:045 USER_DEBUG [27]|DEBUG|BillingStreet San Miguel 1*

*08:39:06:045 USER_DEBUG [28]|DEBUG|Name Test Community*

- If I run it with the Guest User, the log shows **null** for the address but not for the Account name:

*09:00:55:137 USER_DEBUG [29]|DEBUG|Address str **null***

*09:00:55:137    USER_DEBUG [30]|DEBUG|BillingStreet **null***

*09:00:55:137 USER_DEBUG    [31]|DEBUG|Name Test Community*

He have set permission to the guest profile for the account object and for the BillingAddress field as shown bellow: 
[image: Billing address permissions]

Do you know what else needs to be done?

Thank you

Comment: Go through OWD and Sharing settings of the object once.

Comment: I changed it to public read only and it worked, post it as an answer and I will mark it as solved. Thank you

Comment: Glad! Posted as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do check OWD and Sharing settings of the object once, that should help.
Before changing the any sharing settings, please check that it does not affects business in any way.